# Creating an entry with a matrix field using GraphQL

Tags: craft3, matrix, graphql

I am trying to create a new entry in Craft CMS using GraphQL. The entry has a matrix field called "vehicles" that has a single block called "vehicle". This block has a single field called "vehicleValue".

[image]

In GraphiQL I am using the following query to save a new entry:

```
mutation SaveVehicle($vehicles: vehicles_MatrixInput) {
  save_applications_application_Entry(vehicles: $vehicles) {
    uid
    vehicles {
      ... on vehicles_vehicle_BlockType {
        vehicleValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I pass the following variables:

```
{
  "vehicles": {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "vehicle": {
          "vehicleValue": 111
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The query runs and a new entry is created but the matrix field is empty.

The schema is public so no auth is required.

I am new to using Craft and GraphQL so it is probably something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```graphql
mutation SaveVehicle($vehicles: [vehicles_MatrixBlockContainerInput], $sortOrder: [QueryArgument]) {
  save_applications_application_Entry(vehicles: {blocks: $vehicles, sortOrder: $sortOrder}) {
        uid
        vehicles {
            ...on vehicles_vehicle_BlockType {
                vehicleValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your variables:

```json
{
    "sortOrder":"new1",
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "vehicle": {
                "id": "new1", 
                "vehicleValue": "111"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more info [in the documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#matrix-fields-in-mutations).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed! Works perfectly.