# Using a GraphQL mutation query to create matrix blocks

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to write a GraphQL query which creates matrix blocks. The information in the docs as well as [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/creating-an-entry-with-a-matrix-field-using-graphql) didn't help to get it working.

This is what the field settings look like:
[image]

This is my query:

```
mutation saveEntry(
    $biography: [biography_MatrixBlockContainerInput]
    $sortOrder: [QueryArgument]
    $info: String
    $authorId: ID
    $siteId: Int
    $title: String
) {
    save_artist_default_Entry(
        biography: { blocks: $biography, sortOrder: $sortOrder }
        info: $info
        authorId: $authorId
        siteId: $siteId
        title: $title
    ) {
        id
        title
        info
    }
}
```

And here my variables:

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "info": "info",
    "authorId": 1,
    "siteId": 1,
    "sortOrder": [
        "new1"
    ],
    "biography": [
        {
            "biosection": {
                "sortOrder": "new1",
                "headline": "test",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) (API client) to test the query, I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "craft\\services\\Gql::executeQuery(): Argument #3 ($variables) must be of type ?array, string given, called in /Users/xxx/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/GraphqlController.php on line 195"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know why it says Argument #3 causes the error. I changed the order but the error message never changes.
If I remove the "biography" block from the variables, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, I see a typo in your variables (extra `,` after `"headline": "test",`), and you should be passing an `id` to the block, not `sortOrder` ([see docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/graphql.html#matrix-fields-in-mutations)). Try the below as variables and it should work:

```json
{
    "title": "test",
    "info": "info",
    "authorId": 1,
    "siteId": 2,
    "sortOrder": [
        "new1"
    ],
    "biography": [
        {
            "biosection": {
                "id": "new1",
                "headline": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```